# Impact of labeling in a bloch-crystal with orbital basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, crystals, tight-binding

If I'm diagonalizing a hamiltonian of electrons in a crystal that is written in the orbital basis, does it matter whether I calculate the matrix element between one atom and another atom (or the image of the other atom)? If it's not clear what I am asking, please look at the following illustration. In the coordinate system $x$, the atom $B$ has fallen out of the unit cell, say because of a big perturbation, and it is now in the unitcell over to the left. I can "wrap" the coordinate system around by relabeling the atoms (this is the $\tilde x$-coordinate system where I set the name of the image of $B$ to $\tilde B$ ). My impression is that when I come to calculate the matrix elements, the matrix elements are no longer equal. That seems odd because the physics should not change.

[image: To the left is the un-tilde coordinate system where atom B fell outside of the unit cell du to some perturbation. To the right, I have renamed the coordinatesystem x-tilde where the atom B again is inside the unit cell.]

Here is the calculation. I will use that $R_{\tilde A} = R_A$ and $R_{\tilde B} = R_{B} + a$. In addition, I will define the integer $m \equiv n + 1$ at some point.
$$
H^k_{\tilde A \mu \tilde B \nu} = \langle \phi_{\mu,R_{\tilde A}} , H \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty e^{ik n a} \phi_{\nu,R_{\tilde B}+ n a} \rangle = \langle \phi_{\mu,R_{ A}} , H \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty e^{ik n a} \phi_{\nu,R_{B}+ a(n+1)} \rangle = \langle \phi_{\mu,R_{ A}} , H \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty e^{ik (m-1) a} \phi_{\nu,R_{B}+ am} \rangle\\
 =  \langle \phi_{\mu,R_{ A}} , H \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty e^{ik m a}e^{-ik a} \phi_{\nu,R_{B}+ am} \rangle = e^{-ik a} \langle \phi_{\mu,R_{ A}} , H \sum_{m = -\infty}^\infty e^{ik m a} \phi_{\nu,R_{B}+ am} \rangle = e^{-ik a} H^k_{A \mu  B \nu},
$$
where I used that the sum is infinite in the second to last equality.

Can you explain to me about this phenomenon? (1) Does it have a name? (2) How does this effect get dealt with such that labeling of the atoms don't have an impact on the physics? (3) What happens in 3 dimensions?